# Wondering why the condition for the else statement continues to be the output. Using String Variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("In:");
String name = inp.nextLine();

if(inp.equals("Chen")){
  System.out.print("teacher");
}

else{
  System.out.print("student");
}

}
}
```

Continuously keep getting "student" no matter how much I play with the If portion. Not missing capitalization of the name Chen and even tried to store Chen in a variable and have that as part of the condition and still end with the else.

Comment: You should compare it with ``name`` not ``inp``

Comment: I tried that as well but still comes out with the else condition.

Comment: Because `inp` is a `Scanner` (not a `String`) it will **never** be equals to `Chen`. You probably meant `name.equals("Chen")` or `name.equalsIgnoreCase("Chen")` - but `inp.equals("Chen")` is (as you note) **always `false`**.

Comment: Thank you Elliot Frisch that fixed it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have compared a `Scanner` object with a `String` object. Do it as follows:

```
if ("Chen".equals(name)) {
    System.out.print("teacher");
} else {
    System.out.print("student");
}
```

**Additional note:**

If you want to do the comparison in a case-insensitive way, you should use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

```
if ("Chen".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
    System.out.print("teacher");
} else {
    System.out.print("student");
}
```

**Further additional note:**

You can make it shorter by using the ternary operator e.g. the following line is equivalent to the complete whole block of code i.e. `if() {..} else {..}` mentioned above.

```
System.out.println("Chen".equalsIgnoreCase(name) ? "teacher" : "student");
```

Comment: Additional additional note: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), `if ("Chen".equalsIgnoreCase(name))` for cases where `name` *might* be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, @ElliottFrisch for the valuable suggestion. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is easy to solve. Just type in

```
if(name.equals("Chen")){
System.out.print("teacher");
}
```

Because you save the value of your input in the String name. That should fix the issue